# How to fix Nintendo Switch screen stretched vertically on 5:4 monitor?

Tags: nintendo-switch, monitor

I have a Nintendo Switch plugged into an old 5:4 (1024x1080) monitor. The screen is stretched vertically pretty badly. I'd rather have a non-stretched image that doesn't completely fill the screen, aka black bars on the top and bottom of the screen, but I can't find a way to do this on the Switch settings or monitor settings. How do I get my Switch/monitor to stop stretching the image?

Comment: Does this help? [How to adjust screen](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=O_h4eexYrqM)